# Cache of Videos

Tags: android, caching

I am trying to cache of videos by this

```
try {       
    URL oracle = new URL(url);
    URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
    InputStream in = yc.getInputStream();

    File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir() ,url);

    if(!file.exists()){
        file.setReadable(true);
        file.createNewFile();
        if (file.canWrite()){

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);   

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ( (len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                out.write(buffer,0, len1);
            }

            out.close();
        }

        in.close();

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 755 "+getCacheDir() +"/"+ url);  
        videoView.setVideoPath("chmod 755 "+getCacheDir() +"/"+ url);

    }else {

        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUrl));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUrl));    
MediaController mc = new MediaController(VideoViewC.this);
videoView.setMediaController(mc);
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();          
mc.show();
```

But I found Error java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer.

if you have any suggestion please give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have my case problem, and it consisted in particular the my http server, which if not properly authenticate just closed the client connection, it is my Ask:

[android-async-http Status code and response to onFailure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333959/android-async-http-status-code-and-response-to-onfailure)

Maybe you have it too, due to the peculiarities of your httpservers

Did you implement caching video files?