# android-async-http Status code and response to onFailure

Tags: android, http, loopj, android-async-http

if failure authorization my http server send response: 401, binary "401" and send "close socket"

When i test it, send command in CURL, i have:

> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 
>   date: Sat, 12 Oct 2013 10:16:31 GMT
>   content-length: 3 
>   connection: close
>
> 401

Its AllRight)

BUT, My Loopj client:

```
 public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {
  Log.e("ERROR CONNECT", "ERROR CONNECT:::::::::::::" + response + "|" + e + "|");
 }
```

`ERROR CONNECT:::::::::::::can't resolve host|java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer|`

Why i have this response: `can't resolve host` ???

And how i can get response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My http server send response: 401, binary "401" and send "close socket"
send "close socket" - it is not a standard situation for the client, and this on the client side exception occurs: java.net.SocketException, and this is the explanation for "Connection reset by peer".